# Can't set bluetooth headset as default output device in OS X using CoreAudio API

Tags: c++, macos, core-audio, bluetoothheadset

I am having difficulty programmatically setting my Bluetooth headset (Apple Airpods) as the default audio output device on my OSX. I have attempted to use the CoreAudio API to set the device as default, but it does not appear to be working.

In my audio recording program, I create an aggregate audio device that involves the Bluetooth headset device and the blackhole device. The program correctly remembers the Bluetooth headset device name and obtains the AudioDeviceID from the name. After recording, the program removes the aggregate audio device created and then attempts to set the Bluetooth headset device as the default output device using AudioObjectSetPropertyData(). However, even though the function returns a success result (noErr), the device is not set as default.

Before quitting the recording, I check again to see if the default output device is the same as the previous one. If it shows differently, I try to set it again once more. However, it returns success again but does not set it as default yet.

I am unsure if this is an issue with the implementation of the function or if the function itself is failing. If anyone has any suggestions or has experienced a similar issue, I would greatly appreciate any help or advice.

```
#include <CoreAudio/AudioHardware.h>
#include <CoreAudio/AudioServerPlugIn.h>

OSStatus SetDefaultOutputDeviceFromName(const char *_name = nullptr)
{
    OSStatus err = noErr;
    if(_name != nullptr)
    {
        std::string log_ = "[Destroy Aggregate Device]: Selected loopback device name: " + std::string(_name) +  "\n";
        synchronized_logger_function(log_);
        AudioDeviceID deviceID = findDeviceIDFromDeviceName(_name);
        if(deviceID == kAudioObjectUnknown) {
           std::cerr << "Error in getting Device Id from name\n";
        }
        else 
        {
            AudioObjectPropertyAddress defaultDeviceAOPA;
            defaultDeviceAOPA.mSelector = kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice;
            defaultDeviceAOPA.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;
            defaultDeviceAOPA.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMain;

            err = AudioObjectSetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &defaultDeviceAOPA, 0, NULL, sizeof(AudioDeviceID), &deviceID);
            // pause again to give the changes time to take effect
            CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0.1, false);

            if (err)
            {
                // printf("[Remove Aggregate Device]: Error setting default output device: %d\n", err);
            }           
            else
            {
                // printf("[Create Aggregate Device]: Previous device set as default output device.\n");
            }
        }
        // MA_ASSERT(deviceID != kAudioObjectUnknown);
    }
    return noErr;
}

OSStatus DestroyAggregateDevice(AudioDeviceID inDeviceToDestroy, const char *_name = nullptr)
{
    OSStatus osErr = noErr;

    //-----------------------
    // Start by getting the base audio hardware plugin
    //-----------------------

    // UInt32 outSize;
    // Boolean outWritable;
    // osErr = AudioHardwareGetPropertyInfo(kAudioHardwarePropertyPlugInForBundleID, &outSize, &outWritable);
    // if (osErr != noErr) return osErr;

    AudioObjectPropertyAddress propertyAddress = {
        kAudioHardwarePropertyPlugInForBundleID,
        kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
        kAudioObjectPropertyElementMain};

    UInt32 outSize = 0;
    // Boolean writable = false;

    OSStatus err = AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize(
        kAudioObjectSystemObject,
        &propertyAddress,
        0,
        NULL,
        &outSize);

    if (err != noErr)
    {
        // Handle error
        synchronized_logger_function(std::string("[Destroy aggregate device]: Error occured in removing aggregate device\n"));
    }

    AudioValueTranslation pluginAVT;

    CFStringRef inBundleRef = CFSTR("com.apple.audio.CoreAudio");
    AudioObjectID pluginID;

    pluginAVT.mInputData = &inBundleRef;
    pluginAVT.mInputDataSize = sizeof(inBundleRef);
    pluginAVT.mOutputData = &pluginID;
    pluginAVT.mOutputDataSize = sizeof(pluginID);
    osErr = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &propertyAddress, 0, NULL, &outSize, &pluginAVT);
    // osErr = AudioHardwareGetProperty(kAudioHardwarePropertyPlugInForBundleID, &outSize, &pluginAVT);
    if (osErr != noErr)
        return osErr;

    //-----------------------
    // Feed the AudioDeviceID to the plugin, to destroy the aggregate device
    //-----------------------

    AudioObjectPropertyAddress pluginAOPA;
    pluginAOPA.mSelector = kAudioPlugInDestroyAggregateDevice;
    pluginAOPA.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;
    pluginAOPA.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMain;
    UInt32 outDataSize;

    osErr = AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize(pluginID, &pluginAOPA, 0, NULL, &outDataSize);
    if (osErr != noErr)
    {
        return osErr;
    }

    osErr = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(pluginID, &pluginAOPA, 0, NULL, &outDataSize, &inDeviceToDestroy);
    if (osErr != noErr)
    {
        return osErr;
    }
    // pause again to give the changes time to take effect
    CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0.1, false);

    SetDefaultOutputDeviceFromName(_name);

    return noErr;
}
```

Comment: I suspect Apple don't want you to do this and have therefore disabled it.

Comment: So this means that we can't set bluetooth headset audio device as default output device programmatically using core audio api? It never happens in line headset or other speakers device.

Comment: Oh, right (would've been useful to know that).  Maybe it's not possible for aggregate devices then.  That's a theory you could easily test.